# Server side real time analysis of video streamed from client

Tags: webrtc, kurento, mediasoup

I'm trying to build a system for real-time analysis on server for video streamed from the client using WebRTC.

Here is what I currently have in mind. I would capture the webcam video stream from the client and send it (compressed using H.264?) to my server.

On my server, I would receive the stream and every raw frame to my C++ library for analysis.

The output of the analysis (box coordinates to draw) would then be sent back to the client via WebRTC or a separate WebSocket connection.

I've been looking online and found open-source media server like Kurento and Mediasoup but, since I only need to read the stream (no dispatch to other clients), do I really need to use an existing server? Or could I build it myself and if so, where to start?

I'm fairly new to the WebRTC and video streaming world in general so I was wondering, does this whole thing sound right to you?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how real-time your requirements are. If you want 30-60fps and near-realtime, getting the images to the server via RTP is the best solution. And then you'll need things like a jitter buffer, depacketization etc, video decoders, etc.

If you require only one image per second, grabbing it from the canvas and sending it via Websockets or HTTP POST is easier. https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-cv-tensorflow/ shows how to do that in Python.